# How to fix strings or pointers in c?

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on a conversion programming assignment. We have to convert lbs to kgs and vice versa but when I run my code, here is the output

100kgs = 220 (blank)

in the spot where it says blank, the letters "lbs" wont show up. Any idea why???

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>


void convert_weight(int weight1, char units1[], int* weight2, char units2[])
{

    int l = strcmp(units1, "lbs");
    int k = strcmp(units1, "kgs");


    if(l == 0) {

        *weight2 = weight1 /2.2;
        units2 = "kgs";
    }
    else {
        if(k == 0)
        {

        *weight2 = weight1 *2.2;
        units2 ="lbs";
    }
    }


}

int main() {
  char newline, another = 'y';
  int weight1, weight2;
  char units1[4], units2[4]; // length 4 because of '\0'
  while (another == 'y') {
    printf("Enter a weight and the units of the weight (lbs or kgs)\n");
    scanf("%d %s", &weight1, units1);
    convert_weight(weight1, units1, &weight2, units2);
    printf("%d %s = %d %s\nAnother (y or n)\n", weight1, units1, weight2, units2); 
    scanf("%c%c", &newline, &another)    ;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: U are reassigning char array ,

Comment: Don't forget to use "const" when you pass pointers parameter to a function which are not modified by the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the unit string to `unit2` not simply assign it in `convert_weight`.

I can't remember the function for sure but I think it's :

```
strncpy(unit2,"xxx",max);
```

Where max is a new bounds check `int` that you must also pass, taken as `sizeof(unit2)` in the calling code, so:

```
convert_weight(..., units2,sizeof(unit2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as convert:

```
void convert_weight(int weight1, char units1[4], int *weight2, char units2[4])
{
  if (strcmp(units1, "lbs") == 0)
    {
      *weight2 = weight1 / 2.2;
      strcpy(units2, "kgs");
    }
  else if (strcmp(units1, "kgs") == 0)
    {
      *weight2 = weight1 * 2.2;
      strcpy(units2, "lbs");
    }
  else
    printf("Invalid units: %s\n", units1);
  units2[3] = 0; // '\0'                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Comment: You should never, ever use functions which don't check bounds in C like strcpy. Always use the bounds checking versions.